# Oracle SQL Developer Insert statements prompting for value

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm testing a script which deletes a series of values in SQLDeveloper. To be safe, I had SQLDeveloper generate Insert statements for all existing data, so I could restore it if something went wrong. One of the statements is like:

```
Insert into MY_TABLE (KEY,VALUE) values ('key1','https://somewhere.com/index.html?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3');
```

When I run this statement, again in SQLDeveloper, it prompts me to enter values for param2 and param3, as if the & is a signal for interaction. Is there a way to turn this off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need the following at the start of your script:

```
SET DEFINE OFF;
```

I've seen references to `SET SCAN OFF` as well, but turning off `DEFINE` has always worked for me.